# array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in common.inc line number 7259

Tags: php, nginx, error-handling, drupal, drupal-7

This is what I got from my nginx log.

2021/05/27 17:26:27 [error] 24466#24466: *31 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/html/mysite/includes/common.inc on line 7259

```
function drupal_schema_fields_sql( $table, $prefix = NULL) {
7258   $schema = drupal_get_schema($table);
7259   $fields = array_keys($schema['fields']);
7260   if ($prefix) {
7261     $columns = array();
7262     foreach ($fields as $field) {
7263       $columns[] = "$prefix.$field";
7264     }
7265     return $columns;
7266   }
7267   else {
7268     return $fields;
7269   }
7270 }
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: check $schema['fields']. it must be an array like the error says

Comment: Try printing the $schema value and check if the fields parameter is null which probably is. If so that means that your table has no fields

Comment: same file and same database is running in other server and its not giving any error. how's that possible

Answer (score 0):

```
array_keys ( array $array ) : array
```

It expects array as param. In your case $schema['fields']. doesnt seem to be an array.

Try var_dump to check whether fields array exists

```
var_dump($schema);
```

Comment: How to check which table's data the schema is fetching

Comment: Whats the issue ?  Did you try `var_dump($schema);`

Comment: Yes, It's showing arrays in the page using var_dump()

Comment: @AyanantaChakraborty Do you still need support ? Is it solved or not

Comment: Few php extensions were missing in the server that's why it was throwing the error. It's resolved now.